# Is the fundamental group of the Projective Line of order 2?

Tags: projective-geometry, fundamental-groups, linear-groups

While reading an answer to a different question i encountered the statement of the heading; that is "*...the fundamental group of the Projective line is of order 2; then taking the homomorphism...etc."*

My (rather dumb) question is regarding the order 2 of the related fundamental group: what does it means for a linear group to be of order n?**

What is the order of the fundental group of a projective plane P2?

Thanks in advance. Greetings

**Does it have something to do with the cyclical-subspaces of a linear transformation T, the direct-sum of n-invariant subspaces, etc?

Comment: It’s the number of elements. The fundamental group of the real projective plane is Z/2

Comment: Thank you! Is Z2 the additive group of integers módulo-2, by the way?

Comment: Yes, but the fundamental group of the projective line isn't order $2$. The fundamental group of the real projective line $\mathbb{RP}^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ and the fundamental group of the complex projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is trivial. What's true is that the fundamental group of $\mathbb{RP}^n$ has order $2$ when $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps you could suggest me some link with a rationale of the fundamental group of P1 being Z (it could be of the sort of: an action could be defined between Z and P1?). Greetings

Comment: The real projective line is a circle. You can find the computation of the fundamental group of a circle in any textbook on algebraic topology, e.g. Hatcher.

Comment: Thanks for the reference book! Is the betold fundamental group the so called "fundamental homotopy group"? Greetings!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan oops I misread that line. Thanks

Comment: @Atha: it’s sometimes called the first homotopy group.

Comment: Thanks a lot , greetings